# sap.m.TileContainer Only Displays 2 Tiles

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I'd like to use [sap.m.TileContainer](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.TileContainer) to display tiles with some info. The SAP sample is not really useful as it does not follow the guidelines such as using manifest.json etc...

So I built an app in SAP Web IDE from scratch. I am using TileContainer to display tiles. Its `tile` aggregation is bound to a local JSON data file.

The data file contains an array with three items. However, only two are displayed after rendering. Any suggestions why?

This is my data.json:

```
{
    "TileCollection": [{
        "title": "Slovenská Republika",
        "info": "support for SR",
        "flag": "",
        "icon": "sap-icon://inbox"
    }, {
        "title": "Deutschland",
        "info": "support for DE",
        "flag": "",
        "icon": "sap-icon://inbox"
    }, {
        "title": "Ceska Republika",
        "info": "support for CZ",
        "flag": "",
        "icon": "sap-icon://inbox"
    }]
}
```

This is my XML view:

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="com.support_page.controller.App"
    height="100%"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <Page
        showHeader="true"
        enableScrolling="false">
        <TileContainer
            id="container"
            tileDelete="handleTileDelete"
            tiles="{/TileCollection}">
            <StandardTile
                icon="{icon}"
                title="{title}"
                info="{info}"
                activeIcon="{flag}"/>
        </TileContainer>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't see why it should display only two tiles from the current code. Any error message in the browser console? Are you [disabling the cache](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#change_loading_behavior) when updating the page? What does `yourTileContainer.getBinding("tiles").getLength()` return?

Comment: Btw. [`sap.m.TileContainer`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.TileContainer/overview) as well as all the Tiles except of `sap.m.GenericTile` are deprecated as of version 1.50. Just as a side note..

Comment: no error in console, cache is not disabled.
yourTileContainer.getBinding("tiles").getLength() = 0 in onInit or onBeforeRendering or even onAfterRendering

Comment: if tileContainer is to be deprecated, what should be used instead?
also, where did you get that info from?

Comment: I meant, it's better to disable the cache so that the browser doesn't display outdated data when it's updated. About the deprecation: You can see the notice in the current nightly version of the API Reference that I linked to in the previous comment. It says "Deprecated since 1.50. replaced by a container of your choice with [sap.m.GenericTile](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.GenericTile) instances".

Comment: so how do i manage to populate my view with tiles based on json ?
i do not wish to do it manually one by one, but tilecontainer somehow doesnt work.
for the future how would you use the generic tile? as an aggregation of what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for your suggestion

in the meantime i solved it with tile container as well.

what i did is that i used NOT a default model.
i initialised the model in component.js
then used model>/TileCollection and it worked though i am still a bit confused.
nevertheless, thanks for you answer as well.

Comment: Glad you could solve the problem. You can also accept your own answer to inform others about it. But what was the part that was a bit confusing?

Answer (score -1):

```
I solved this issue , even i was facing same issue , If you dont use local model you will not face issue or if you define your model in controller you will not face the issue.
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function(Controller,JSONModel) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("SmartPurchaseReq.controller.Home", {

        /**
         * Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if available) are already created.
         * Can be used to modify the View before it is displayed, to bind event handlers and do other one-time initialization.
         * @memberOf SmartPurchaseReq.view.Home
         */
            onInit: function() {
                var that = this;
                var data = {
    "TileCollection" : [
        {
            "icon" : "sap-icon://hint",
            "type" : "Monitor",
            "title" : "Tiles: a modern UI design pattern for overview & navigation."
        },
        {
            "icon" : "sap-icon://inbox",
            "number" : "89",
            "title" : "Approve Leave Requests",
            "info" : "Overdue",
            "infoState" : "Error"
        },
        {
            "type" : "Create",
            "title" : "Create Leave Requests",
            "info" : "28 Days Left",
            "infoState" : "Success"
        },
        {
            "icon" : "sap-icon://travel-expense-report",
            "number" : "281",
            "numberUnit" : "euro",
            "title" : "Travel Reimbursement",
            "info" : "1 day ago"
        },
        {
            "icon" : "sap-icon://loan",
            "number" : "2380",
            "numberUnit" : "euro",
            "title" : "My Salary",
            "info" : "8 days ago"
        },
        {
            "icon" : "sap-icon:`enter code here`//lab",
            "number" : "1",
            "numberUnit" : "Invention",
            "title" : "Test Lab Reports",
            "info" : "8 Days Ago"
        },
        {
            "icon" : "sap-icon://inbox",
            "type" : "Monitor",
            "title" : "Leave Request History"
        },
        {
            "type" : "Create",
            "title" : "Create Purchase Order",
            "info" : "890€ Open Budget",
            "infoState" : "Success"
        },
        {
            "icon" : "sap-icon://stethoscope",
            "number" : "3",
            "title" : "Yearly Health Check",
            "info" : "3 year overdue",
            "infoState" : "Error"
        },
        {
            "icon" : "sap-icon://meal",
            "type" : "Monitor",
            "title" : "Meal Schedule"
        }

    ]
};
                 var DummyModel = new JSONModel(); 
                 DummyModel.setData(data);
                // var sPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("model", "/Dummy.json");
                // var DummyModel = new JSONModel(sPath);
                that.getView().byId("container").setModel(DummyModel);
            },
            OnTilePress: function(evt) {
                var idj = evt.getSource();
                var d =5;
            }

        /**
         * Similar to onAfterRendering, but this hook is invoked before the controller's View is re-rendered
         * (NOT before the first rendering! onInit() is used for that one!).
         * @memberOf SmartPurchaseReq.view.Home
         */
        //  onBeforeRendering: function() {
        //
        //  },

        /**
         * Called when the View has been rendered (so its HTML is part of the document). Post-rendering manipulations of the HTML could be done here.
         * This hook is the same one that SAPUI5 controls get after being rendered.
         * @memberOf SmartPurchaseReq.view.Home
         */
        //  onAfterRendering: function() {
        //
        //  },

        /**
         * Called when the Controller is destroyed. Use this one to free resources and finalize activities.
         * @memberOf SmartPurchaseReq.view.Home
         */
        //  onExit: function() {
        //
        //  }

    });

});
```